# Retrieving tasks within teams in PHP

Tags: php, asana, asana-connect, asana-api

I am trying to develop a web application that can fetch data from Asana and generate custom spreadsheet reports. [This](https://github.com/ajimix/asana-api-php-class) wrapper class was very helpful in making things simple.

However, I am having a hard time in writing code that gets me the team/s that a particular task belongs to. Even when I export data as JSON through Asana's web application the 'teams' find no mention. From what I understand, Asana itself does not provide an association between teams and tasks. Please correct me if I am wrong.

But if I am right at my conclusion, is there a workaround I could use? Teams are an important part of my data rendering and I need them to be mapped correctly in my reports that I am trying to generate from Asana. The report I want to generate would be hierarchical in nature.

- Organisation

  - Team

    - Projects

      - Tasks

        - Subtask

Can I do something to achieve this hierarchy? The only place I get stuck is getting the projects under a particular team.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to hear that you found that wrapper useful. We will be releasing a PHP Library ourselves soon that you may be interested in. Stay tuned!

Below is some pseudo-code to derive the hierarchy you are looking for, I think. Let me know if it helps.

[GET /workspaces](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/workspaces#get-all)

```
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 1234,
          "name": "Startup Inc"
        }
      ]
    }
```

[GET /workspaces/1234](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/workspaces#get)

```
    {
      "data": {
        "id": 1234,
        "name": "Startup Inc",
        "is_organization": true,
        ...
      }
    }
```

Because is_corganization is true, we can then continue...

[GET /organizations/organization-id/teams](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/teams#get)

```
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 9876,
          "name": "Ninja Team"
        }
      ]
    }
```

[GET /teams/9876/projects](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/projects#query)

```
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 5678,
          "name": "Stealth Project"
        }
      ]
    }
```

[GET /projects/5678/tasks](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#query)

```
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": 8675309,
          "name": "Top secret video"
        }
      ]
    }
```

[GET /tasks/8675309](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#get)

```
    {
      "data": {
        "id": 8675309,
        "created_at": "2015-03-25T17:28:59.255Z",
        "modified_at": "2015-05-15T03:13:28.754Z",
        "name": "Top secret video",
        "notes": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WTdTwcmxyo",
        "completed": false,
        ... # All the task data
        ]
      }
    }
```